# how to do twitter login on a website javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've been looking for how to login with twitter. i found something about twitter @anywhere but it seems that this options has been taken down. does anyone know if there is an other way on how to login with twitter on a website ?

Comment: I think you won't simply implement Twitter Login flow with JavaScript because Twitter doesn't provide any client-Side procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the official tutorial for "Implementing Sign in with Twitter":

https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing

Answer (score 0):

Always when you face something like that go directly to the developer API

https://dev.twitter.com/

And if you are using PHP you can take look at this awesome library

http://www.eden-php.com/

I hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

To create a third party login system for your website using twitter go this article:
http://onlinewebapplication.com/login-facebook-twitter-php/

You will see they have a tutorial with files explaining the process.

Here is the official twitter documentation:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

Before you start copying and pasting code it may be helpful to think through every step of the process and each landing page.

- Login Page
- Does user have account Y/N
- If N then sign up page (then do they have to go back and log in to your site?)
- If Y enter credentials (then redirect to desired page)